# Javascript Console Clear disables all console logs instead of clearing

Tags: javascript

My main.js file is loaded within index.html, and starts with

```
console.clear();
```

So I get a clean console before the project starts.
Strangely, any logs that follow console.clear aren't shown anymore either!

```
console.clear();
console.log("starting the project");
console.log("but these logs are not shown...");
```

How can I clear the console and then start logging messages?

Answer (score 3):

Works good for me http://jsfiddle.net/3rd26za5/

```
console.log("before clear");
console.clear();
console.log("starting the project");
console.log("but these logs are not shown...");
```

Comment: This shows the same issue for me in Safari. In Chrome it works OK. Must be a safari bug then?

Comment: yeah, looks like safari issue, in chrome and FF looks good, so probably for debug you should use them.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
console.clear();
console.log("This prints normally.");
```

Output:

```
This prints normally.
```

Works for me. Must be a bug in the software you are using.

Comment: Indeed. The bug shows in Safari only. In chrome it works fine.

Comment: @Kokodoko Hm, I use firefox, there's also a built-in website IDE, and cool debugger stuff. In my opinion, you should use it (because Chrome really eats up your RAM >.<)